# Group By calculated column doesn't show values in list view

Tags: 2013, 2010, list-view, view

ENV : SharePoint Server 2013

Language : French

We've migrated a list from a 2010 site collection (in our 2013 environment) to a 2013 site collection using the Export-SPWeb function.

In the 2010 site collection, we're using the "Group By" statement on a calculated column. Formula is as follows :

[image]

and the view shows the values correctly :

[image]

But after migrating the list in the 2013 site, "group by" values aren't shown anymore (Formula is the same):

[image]

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try creating a new test column using the same formula as before and group on that. Just to test if it is some problem with the migration.

Comment: Same issue with the test column.

Comment: Yes - this seems to be a SP 2013 issue with dates used in calculated date columns. Works okay on the original date column. I will post a possible work around as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does appear to be an issue with SP 2013 when using a calculated column on a date field returned as a date. The usual reason for doing this is when you have an original data column with a name that you don't want to have displayed. So you create a calculated column with the new name.

```
=[Original Date Column Name]
```

The only workaround I have found is to return the date as a single line of text and use the following formula to create the date. Because strings are sorted alphanumerically you will need to return YYYY_MM_DD and this will need some zero padding for months and days <10.

```
=YEAR(Date)&"_"& IF(LEN(MONTH(Date))=1,"0","")&MONTH(DATE)&"_"& IF(LEN(DAY(Date))=1,"0","")&DAY(Date)
```